# Customize text/look of facebook's send button

Tags: html, facebook, fbml

I would like to customize the look&feel of the facebook send button. Instead of using "send" as a label I'd like to use something like: "send to friend". Is it also possibile to use a fully custom design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/).

See the "Javascript SDK" section of that document for the easiest way to do it.  Basically, you'll call [FB.ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) in the onclick handler of whatever button you want.

If you can, I would recommend using the display=iframe mode, rather than causing a popup.